# Regarding No OUPTPUT in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am using ncurses to prepare a simple menu in the main window having 5 options and choosing them with the help of arrow keys.At present i had prepared a program to only display a menu in the screen with 5 options only,but some how the output is coming as a blank screen.Please help me out in finding out the error in my code.

```
#include<ncurses.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//#define ENTER 10
//#define ESCAPE 27

void init_curses()
{initscr();
start_color();
init_pair(1,COLOR_WHITE,COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(2,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_WHITE);
init_pair(3,COLOR_RED,COLOR_WHITE);
curs_set(0);
noecho();
keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
}

void draw_mainmenu(WINDOW *mainmenu)
{ wbkgd(mainmenu,COLOR_PAIR(2));
  waddstr(mainmenu, "HELLO THIVNENT");
  move(1,0);
  waddstr(mainmenu, "HELLO THIVNENT 1");
move( 2,0);
  waddstr(mainmenu, "HELLO THIVNENT 2");
move( 3,0);
  waddstr(mainmenu, "HELLO THIVNENT 3");
move( 4,0);
  waddstr(mainmenu, "HELLO THIVNENT 4");
move( 5,0);
  waddstr(mainmenu, "HELLO THIVNENT 5");
wattroff(mainmenu,COLOR_PAIR(3));
}


int main()
{
  int key;
  WINDOW *mainmenu;
  init_curses();
  bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(1));
  mainmenu=subwin(stdscr,1,80,0,0);
  draw_mainmenu(mainmenu);
sleep(3);
refresh();

delwin(mainmenu);
endwin();
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `refresh()` before `sleep()`

```
refresh();
sleep(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exactly the correct one. The problem is that the `sleep(3)` function is placed before the `refresh()` causing refresh after 3 seconds and immediately you are trying to delete the window, and of course you will not be able to see it. There are two approaches that fixes the problem.

- Remove the `sleep(3)` and insert a `getch()` after `refresh()` fixes the issue. The window will now stay until you press a key instead for 3 seconds.
- Place the `sleep(3)` after `refresh()`